# Is it possible to have your stock dividends sent directly to your house or personal bank account instead of your brokerage account?

Tags: bank-account, dividends

Is it possible to have your stock dividends sent directly to your house or personal bank account instead of your brokerage account?

Comment: Do you mean "cash dividends on stock" or "stock dividends", meaning dividends paid in more shares?

Answer (score 14):

Possible?  Sure.  Wise, probably not.

Your brokerage likely has an option where you can request physical shares for a fee.  If you request physical shares, those shares will be registered directly to you rather than being held in [street name](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/185.asp) by your broker on your behalf.  Since the shares are registered to you directly, the company will send you dividend checks directly rather than sending them to your broker.

But this is probably not something you want to do.  You'd need to ensure that the shares are kept safe.  It would take additional time, effort, and fees to sell your shares in the future-- you'd realistically need to send the shares back to your broker, wait for them to get deposited into your account, potentially pay an additional fee for the deposit, and then trade them.  And you have to remember to notify all the companies you hold shares in when you move.

Practically, if you want your dividends, it almost certainly makes more practical sense to let them send the funds to your brokerage account and then set up an automatic transfer that moves the money to your checking account.

Comment: Are stock dividends paid as more shares or as cash? Your answer seems to assume that dividends are paid as additional shares.

Comment: "stock dividends" are paid in stock. "cash dividends" are paid in cash. It's possible that the OP meant "dividends on stock" which are almost always paid in cash.

Comment: OP could sell the physical shares on ebay? ☺

Answer (score 2):

The answer to that is no. This is not how the infrastructure is set up. Note that the company does neither know who you are, nor does it know your bank account. It also does not want the overhead - noone does - to deal with thousands of transfers of small amounts of dividend to various people. This is a very automated industry.

This is what the broker handles. The broker holds them in your name (mostly without associating them with your person because this involves paperwork) and does to at clearing banks that handle the dividend payout - it gets a total amount based on the total shares held by its clients and divides it up to their accounts.

There was a time this was different, where shares were physical paper and that would have coupons for the dividend (a coupon per year, and you get a new sheet when running out) and you could go to the company and demand payment. This time is long gone - today all is done only digital.

Comment: That last paragraph about paper coupons reminds me of bonds, since bond interest payments are fixed.

Comment: *deal with thousands of transfers of small amounts of dividend to various people.  This is a very automated industry* — surely automation should have no problem dealing with thousands of transfers of small amounts to various people?  Payroll systems do that all the time.

Comment: @gerrit sure, but it’s still very expensive, since it’s highly regulated.  Easier to just have Vanguard tell you how much money to send them.

Comment: Yep. Also payroll systems generally do not deal with THAT small amounts regularly. Some dude owning 1 share would incur a serious overhead compared to a pathetic dividend. It is also regulated and risks fraud - so the system set up is in place and you either work with it, or do not work with the financial sector.

Comment: At least in US most companies have stopped issuing paper certificates, but they still allow you to register directly with them (really their transfer agent) and send you dividends directly along with annual reports, other materials like mergers, and proxy solicitations -- in the past these were paper mail, and the company delivered _truckloads_ to a big broker to mail out to their street-name holder clients, but now with electronic delivery common it just means you get an email with a link to proxyvote etc from the company instead of the broker.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have your stock dividends sent directly to your house or personal bank account instead of your brokerage account?

This depends on the jurisdiction. Different jurisdictions have different infrastructure and processes for stock trading. You didn't specify the country, so I will use Malaysia and Singapore as examples. The answer is: yes, it is possible to have cash dividends deposited directly into a personal bank account.

In Malaysia and Singapore, it is common for individual shareholders to hold all their shares under direct registration (as opposed to "street name" registration that is common in some countries). This means that most investors' names appear directly in companies' share registers. Most investors have a personal account at the central share depository, which means that the share depository has most investors' personal information (possibly including bank account information). This easily allows the share depository to provide a service to send dividends directly into personal bank accounts.

Under "street name" registration, it is not so easy to implement such a feature, since shares are registered under the names of stock brokers (or other custodians or nominees) instead of the names of individual investors. The share depository does not have the personal information of each individual investor; it only has information about their stock broker that is holding the shares on the investors' behalf.

---

Notes:

- In Malaysia, the central share depository is the Central Depository System (CDS), and the service for depositing cash dividends directly into bank accounts is [eDividend](https://www.bursamalaysia.com/trade/our_products_services/central_depository_system/edividend).
- In Singapore, the central share depository is the Central Depository (CDP), and the service for depositing cash dividends directly into bank accounts is the [Direct Crediting Service](https://www.sgx.com/apply-services#Direct%20Crediting%20Service) ([FAQ](https://www.sgx.com/cdp/faq/)).

Comment: Not sure I buy that. As in: the CDS just looks like a gigantic mandatory clearing broker.